# Argument of type 'InputType[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GenericType[]' Typescript

Tags: typescript, object, generics, helper, any

my intent here is to write a helper function whose aim is to dynamically sort an array of objects (first argument) in alphabetical order, based on a `key` passed as second argument.

The function:

```
interface GenericObject {
  [key: string]: string;
}

export const sortAlphabetically = (array: Array<GenericObject>, sortBy: keyof GenericObject) => {
  let isKeyValid = false;
  
  // check the key exists in the object before attempting to sort by it
  if (array.length > 0) {
    isKeyValid = array.every(obj => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, sortBy)  && typeof obj[sortBy] === 'string');
  }

  if (isKeyValid) {
    array.sort((a: GenericObject, b: GenericObject) =>
      a[sortBy].toLowerCase() < b[sortBy].toLowerCase()
        ? -1
        : a[sortBy].toLowerCase() > b[sortBy].toLowerCase()
        ? 1
        : 0,
    );
    return array;
  } else {
    return;
  }
};
```

So now, even before being able to test my function, if I try to do this:

```
export interface Person {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
} 

const people: Person[] = [
{name: 'John', surname: 'Smith'},
{name: 'Tony', surname: 'Denver'},
{name: 'Mary', surname: 'Howard'},
]

sortAlphabetically(people, 'name');
```

or this:

```
export interface Car {
  model: string;
  make: string;
} 

const cars: Car[] = [
{model: 'Golf', make: 'Volkswagen'},
{model: 'X1', make: 'BMW'},
{model: 'Clio', make: 'Renault'},
]

sortAlphabetically(cars, 'make');
```

I get the error:
`TS2345: Argument of type 'Person[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GenericObject[]'.   Type 'Person' is not assignable to type 'GenericObject'. Index signature is missing in type 'Person'.`
Same happens for `Car[]`.

As a helper function, the key point is that it needs to adapt to `any` type of object that will be passed inside the array, without complaining about the type.
Therefore I'm quite sure the problem is with the way I'm defining my `GenericObject`.

Can someone point out what I'm missing here? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first thing to say a proper implementation will be troublesome.

What you seek :

1. Pass an array
2. Pass a key that belongs to a string property
3. Sort the array by that key.

For those above you need to do a few things:

- Narrow down the key parameter to allow for only string properties

  - `GenericObject` type not enough to provide this alone
  - You need some type-mapper that filters only string properties
- Since there is no relation between `GenericObject` and `Person` types you can't do this casting:  `array.sort((a: GenericObject, b: GenericObject)`
- If you generalize that array type to `any` ish type then this won't work: `a[sortBy].toLowerCase()` because `.toLowerCase()` has to be applicable to any kind of object property.
  So you need a type guard that will narrow down that property into `GenericObject`

So TL;DR

```js
interface GenericObject {
  [key: string]: string;
}
type FilterFlags<Base, Condition> = {
  [Key in keyof Base]:
  Base[Key] extends Condition ? Key : never
};
type AllowedNames<Base, Condition> =
  FilterFlags<Base, Condition>[keyof Base];
  
type SubType<Base, Condition> =
  Pick<Base, AllowedNames<Base, Condition>>;

export function sort<T>(array: Array<T>, sortBy: keyof SubType<T, string>) {
  let isKeyValid = false;

  // check the key exists in the object before attempting to sort by it
  if (array.length > 0) {
    isKeyValid = array.every(obj => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, sortBy));
  }

  if (isKeyValid) {
    array.sort((a, b) =>
      (isGeneric(a, sortBy) && isGeneric(b, sortBy)) ? // narrow down type to GenericObject so that .toLowerCase becomes valid here
        a[sortBy].toLowerCase() < b[sortBy].toLowerCase()
          ? -1
          : a[sortBy].toLowerCase() > b[sortBy].toLowerCase()
            ? 1
            : 0 : 
            1 // this shouldn't be happening
    );
    return array;
  } else {
    return;
  }
};

const isGeneric = (a: any, key: keyof typeof a): a is GenericObject =>
  typeof a[key] === "string";

export interface Person {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const people: Person[] = [
  { name: 'John', id: 1 },
  { name: 'Tony', id: 2 },
  { name: 'Mary', id: 3 },
]

sort(people, "name"); // this won't allow passing "id" as parameter
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOIRNYCDyAjAKwgTGQG8AoZZAbQGsIBPALmQGcwpQBzAXVY5cQ3ANwUAvhTCMADigBiwADaQo8pXG5sAPACE4bCABpkAYQD2IACbAwwSwD5kAXnJVaAaSbJQyBo3MYZH1DfncQiBovRl5kCAAPSGs2M0sbO0tkAH5kaORWTAA3aAkxaTlkAEElJXMAdwgrADk4AFsIHQiTC2tbexAnZ3dFFWh1TU6DY1TejIH6JkDgqd4xailZFABlAFc8ABVNvSnutL7HF3cABWw6Y8MTatqG5raO++me9P6HBzEKBIycxQUgwHYgEj9djAsDafYOAAUcCgUDgLCqKLRcIcJjYMN06P8S12ByO+1xnB4DgAlG5qEoIKRgGxogA1OBKYBWFzIeBKQz-agAeiFyAQAAtiHRkGBJX5vAlmWAUr5ZShzIRiKQ8BAYMCUHAwJBWjI7MIZeZoSDkHhGD4wO5gEEkZjGAA6BnCWXIJwABlplGo1GZbI5XJ5yNR7ogxSgjARGoILic+CIJDdMig5jA2c2bvFBhwdRAVyzchB7oQHKUCcIuPxjGp1LWyEkjudIaY7M5VgD7mokbRbrxIIRSJMeFpzgc-aDCOZ6EwXAQ46tYAJtIAZJufGxF1gV3h6yCN7SsrOg8g4DQR+uYm6cwAZerQUxTBG07Q2m8N3gP8zPg0UBvoYH4Xpe2TIAAtAAjOBl6sNet4En+T4vsB760k4eA-ie95oUBIEQGBEGkZBcFkRBrC+vkyDwRBMHICKMrisy7DiuYOxKFYIAAOTaigBYyHIIA8LOzazlAjI7FAIBXq6LbiHE-IoIGQZSWAMkgIppQUBQCCWBwu77suPJIohICMCY-isESQTlBASxwNSiG7mgGAHqmWrJu4DlOQsMQuM4rgAESCDwIX-ICMI+OA0DwEgyBXNAeJyWpXIFDsrQ6lALYgG8AiUsIYhtgZIBGXI5gyAyrDJVAqU0LErg0O4ZDIPl7SsLxABS5jinxJgZcgjHiEYrXtQVyC8fsliMLxg1WKwABMrZjdQbUdRAXUALLInNC2sAAzKtFC8Hpt4IpV1XTCFm0hc2QA)

`SubType` type mapper is taken from [here](https://medium.com/dailyjs/typescript-create-a-condition-based-subset-types-9d902cea5b8c)

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time to write this solution. This is indeed a much more elaborated solution than I'd ever thought! I must confess I am finding it a bit hard to understand what's happening with `type FilterFlags`, `type AllowedNames` and `type SubType` and their implications, but I'll carefully read the article you linked. Thanks for your help man!

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't be able to cast a `Person` to a `GenericObject` because `Person` holds `number` and `string` values when `GenericObject` only allows `string` values.

Second, there is an opened issue about the error you are experiencing

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300

You should replace the `interface` with a `type`

---

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxgeQEYCsJuCgF4oBvAKCigG0BrCEALigGdhV4BzAXWbY85QAPlHgBXALZZkAbnIBfcuQgAPMAHskhNOvhtWm4AEEANmAAWAQ2nB0lkyZDEoACktIklplCMevAHjhEVExcfGAAPgAaAy0AIW96EHUAM1gEZHRsPAIASmIIskooAHoSqAB1K2AIADdkBTllNUMoUEgoAAVkFl1nCip4SwkIPnYULjkqFAATZnEpWUaoJR09Qkh1MBNRrp7dam5nanJSIZHmAHIAKXVzeEuY2eYARnko0-Pdy4AVXRBHlBnlAAEzvT7Db4AWXcAKecygAGZwdwlL0tKYLNYILY0PZHC5NtsIDFLl9LrkZEA)

```
type GenericObject = {
  [key: string]: string | number;
}

export const sortAlphabetically = (array: Array<GenericObject>, sortBy: keyof GenericObject) => {
  // Whatever
};

export type Person = {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}; 

const people: Person[] = [
{name: 'John', id: 1},
{name: 'Tony', id: 2},
{name: 'Mary', id: 3},
]

sortAlphabetically(people, 'name');
```

Comment: H, thanks for the answer and for pointing out that ticket. I've edited the `Person` type on the question, as my function will only do sorting in case of a `string`. I've changed the `GenericObject` to be like yours, with only the string type (would `any` do the trick as well?). I changed the your typescript snippet accordingly, I don't get any error in it but unfortunately I do still get the error in my code.

Comment: Here's your snippet, changed: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxgeQEYCsJuCgF4oBvAKCigG0BrCEALigGdhV4BzAXWbY84BucgF9y5NAHt4bVpKTAAggBswACwCGWCMHQblykMSgAKDUiQamURRasAeOIlSZc+YAD4ANHIUAha3oQSQAzWARkdGw8AgBKYg8ySigAehSoAHVNYAgAN2RRYUpQSCgABWQWaWMKKngNAFsIPnYULmEqFgBXJHqmloFhEUEocSkZQkhJMGVm8srpam5janJSPrmAcgApSTV4TZ9u3satgEZNkS81jeZNgBVpEEPWHtuoTYAmS+v107uALLmZ5HN7-D4AZh+5G44iqChU6i0Oj0BhAJimMwgPk2G02sUEQA . I don't get errors in it, but I still get exactly the same error in my code.

Comment: `Person` must be a `type` aswell to not get the error! :)

Comment: Yes I've got it mate, sorry I didn't see you did change both of them! I can confirm I don't get the error in the snippet but I still get it in my code. No idea why.

Comment: Check your version of typescript, it could differ from the one used on the playground

Comment: yeah, my local version is 3.5.2, I would need to upgrade to 4.0.2.... which is a bit of a tricky task as for now. Anyway, in the playground it still works, even after downgrading the version to 3.5.1. It would be interesting to find another workaround to this issue... thanks for your help.